# Update row from ASPxPopupControl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

After clicking on the row the popup (AspxPopupControl) display the data of choosen row. I passed the value from gridView to the popup like this:

```
 function(s, e) {
 grid.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, "BusinessEntityID;FirstName;LastName;JobTitle;Department",     function (value) {
 tb1.SetText(value[0]);
  tb2.SetText(value[1]);
  tb3.SetText(value[2]);
  tb4.SetText(value[3]);
  tb5.SetText(value[4]);
 popupControl.Show();
 });
}
```

How can I now pass values to database to update the table?

Answer (score 0):

if your grid is devexpress grid ; you can write something like this on your button ClientSideEvents.Click :

```js
 function (s,e) {
   $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'yourURL',
            data: JSON.stringify(yourData),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(jsonResult) {
               YourGrid.Refresh(); YourPopUp.Hide(); + @"
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
   });
```

}